# Systemd unit file for swapon does not run on boot

Tags: systemd, coreos, swapfile

I have a systemd unit file that does swapon, but it doesn't seem to run on each boot even though it's enabled.

Here are the contents of my `swapon.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn on swap

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=SWAPFILE=/swapfile-1GB
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=${SWAPFILE} bs=1024 count=1048576
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/mkswap ${SWAPFILE}
ExecStart=/sbin/swapon ${SWAPFILE}

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

This should optionally create the file and make it into a swapfile optionally if it hasn't been done yet, then run swapon on it. It's enabled, but doesn't run on boot; I manually have to run `sudo systemctl start swapon` which does work.

How do I get it to run on boot?

Comment: How do you know it is enabled?

Comment: It's listed and marked as "enabled" when I list all the units

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing `local.target` at the end to `swap.target`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there is a swap unit that can be used to control swapfile activation:

```
[Swap]
What=/swapfile
```

(etc)